# Setup LocalCDN or similar CDN replacer to run locally network-wide

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, browser-addons, tracking, pihole

Big companies like Google, Akamai, Cloudflare, are likely suspects when it comes to tracking, and fingerprinting is a big issue that most people don't know about it. If you have large companies tracking or cross-referencing every library you load, they could probably start to get a picture of who you are and what sites you visit.

Is there a way we can run something like LocalCDN as a standalone program on linux/bsd? Then use a DNS server to replace the CDNs and user certificate to fix SSL.

This could be useful for home networking, office networking, or public networks, as they could employ it to reduce tracking of network users.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the below would all you require, I run a couple of Pi-hole servers with "unbound". Offers a certain level of privacy, which for me is enough.

My setup runs on a couple Ubuntu virtual machines..

Couple of articles on how to configure Pi-hole and unbound:

(Exact steps I've followed to install Pi-hole)
https://cloudtechtips.com/network/installing-pi-hole-on-ubuntu-22-04/13/

(Steps I've followed to install unbound)
https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/dns/unbound/

I also connect to my home network when on the move (mobile devices, smartphones ,laptops) where the above are running using VPN, so I'm always behind Pi-hole.

(Steps I've followed to configure OpenVPN)
https://cloudtechtips.com/linux/ubuntu/installing-openvpn-with-pivpn-on-ubuntu-running-pi-hole/394/